# Real backtest result with 2 MA or EMA crossing, is it possible?

Tags: pine-script

Thank you for your help.

I have fun with Pine Script to learn. I coded a simple strategy which is based on the crosses of 2 MA or EMA with TP for intraday / scalping. I go on small TP of 0.9 or 1% not more

Everything works except necessarily the results of the backtests which are false in any case.

if I don't activate "recalculate afert order i filled" the strategy seems to calculate my take profits correctly. But as the strategy only calculates at the close of the candle, it generates winning trades for more than 1% (so much the better, you tell me). but also if the TP is hit during the current candle and the price does not return to the 1% level on the following candles, it does not count the take profit ... And of course that completely distorts the results.

[image: TP hit in the current candle]

If I activate "recalculate afert order i filled" My tp are calculated correctly each time except when the MA cross in 2 candles (false signals). So this creates 2 orders on the same candle and this further distorts the results.

[image: 2 orders in one candle]

So I don't really know how to get correct backtest results.

Is it possible to prohibit more than 1 signal per candle or to integrate a variable which would allow the calculation of the TP correctly without activating "recalculate afert order i filled"

Maybe I'm wrong and I don't trigger correctly?

here is the code :

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

// Date
startDate = input.int(title="Start Date",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input.int(title="Start Month",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input.int(title="Start Year",
     defval=2019, minval=2018, maxval=2100)

endDate = input.int(title="End Date",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input.int(title="End Month",
     defval=7, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input.int(title="End Year",
     defval=2022, minval=2020, maxval=2100)
    
inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

//EMA
lenema = input.int(13, minval=1, title="Length")
srcema = input(close, title="Source")
offsetema = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
ema = ta.ema(srcema, lenema)
plot(ema, title="EMA", color=color.red, offset=offsetema)

lenma = input.int(30, minval=1, title="Length")
srcma = input(close, title="Source")
offsetma = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
ma = ta.sma(srcma, lenma)
plot(ma, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offsetma)

//Trades conditions
longCondition = ta.crossover(ema, ma)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ema, ma)

    
if (inDateRange and longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (inDateRange and shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) 
    
if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()

// TP
longProfitPerc = input.float(title="--> Long TP (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) / 100

shortProfitPerc = input.float(title="--> Short TP (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) / 100

//TP declanchement
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="L TP", limit=longExitPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="S TP", limit=shortExitPrice)
```

Thank you for your help and have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Strategy calculation happens once per bar, but when you use the "After order execution" checkbox, the strategy calculation engine after each executed order recalculates the strategy and executes orders if there are suitable conditions for them. This happens in your case

[image]

So, at the close of bar #3, the strategy calculation engine performs calculations and determines that the condition for entering a short position is met, a market order is created that will be executed on the next tick, since the current bar closed (this was the last tick after which the calculation takes place) , then the next tick will open bar #4. At the opening of bar #4, the order is executed and the strategy enters a short position, since you use recalculation after the order is filled, the strategy is recalculated, and since there was a reverse intersection (from bar #3 to bar #4), the condition for entering a long position is fulfilled, so the strategy immediately goes long on the first tick. If recalculation after order execution were disabled, then the strategy would be recalculated only at the close of bar #4, and the order could only be executed at the next tick (opening of bar #5)

----------
In order to prevent the order from being re-executed, you need to add a check to the entry conditions for the fact that there has not yet been an entry or exit from the position on the current bar. You can do this by checking the position size change compared to the previous bar, so on recalculation, for example, after the entry order is executed, the value of the position size will change, and if it is not equal to 0, then the entry will not occur. Here is an example (works correctly if the number of contracts to enter long and short is always equal):

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_order_fills=true)

// Date
startDate = input.int(title="Start Date",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input.int(title="Start Month",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input.int(title="Start Year",
     defval=2019, minval=2018, maxval=2100)

endDate = input.int(title="End Date",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input.int(title="End Month",
     defval=7, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input.int(title="End Year",
     defval=2022, minval=2020, maxval=2100)
    
inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

//EMA
lenema = input.int(13, minval=1, title="Length")
srcema = input(close, title="Source")
offsetema = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
ema = ta.ema(srcema, lenema)
plot(ema, title="EMA", color=color.red, offset=offsetema)

lenma = input.int(30, minval=1, title="Length")
srcma = input(close, title="Source")
offsetma = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
ma = ta.sma(srcma, lenma)
plot(ma, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offsetma)

//Trades conditions
longCondition = ta.crossover(ema, ma)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ema, ma)

position_unchanged = ta.change(strategy.position_size) == 0
if (inDateRange and longCondition and position_unchanged)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (inDateRange and shortCondition and position_unchanged)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()

// TP
longProfitPerc = input.float(title="--> Long TP (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) / 100

shortProfitPerc = input.float(title="--> Short TP (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) / 100

//TP declanchement
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="L TP", limit=longExitPrice)
    
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="S TP", limit=shortExitPrice)
```

Comment: HI and thank's for your help.

It's better but still have issue with short entry or signal not fire with 2 signal in 2 candles? Image : https://ibb.co/t8N1gm6 

Any suggestions :) ?